# The "error_marshaling_enabled" setting seems to be always enabled

Tags: tarantool

When I run this code:

```php
$client->evaluate('
    box.session.settings.error_marshaling_enabled = false
    box.error{code = 42, reason = "Foobar", type = "MyError"}
');
```

regardless of the value of `error_marshaling_enabled` I always get a response with a new [(extended)](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.4/dev_guide/internals/box_protocol/#box-protocol-responses-error-extra)  error format:

```php
  [
    49 => 'Foobar',
    82 => [
      0 => [
        0 => [
          0 => 'CustomError',
          2 => 3,
          1 => 'eval',
          3 => 'Foobar',
          4 => 0,
          5 => 42,
          6 => [
            'custom_type' => 'MyError',
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer.

`error_marshaling_enabled` option affects only how error objects are encoded in response body (48, IPROTO_DATA). It does not affect how they are returned as exceptions, in the response header (82, IPROTO_ERROR).

#### Long answer.

In Tarantool an error object can be returned in 2 ways: as an exception and as an object. For example, this is how to throw an error as exception:

```lua
function throw_error()
    box.error({code = 1000, reason = "Error message"})
    -- Or
    error('Some error string')
end
```

This is how to return it as an object:

```lua
function return_error()
    return box.error.new({code = 1000, reason = "Error message"})
end
```

If the function was called remotely, using IPROTO protocol via a connector like netbox, or PHP connector, or any other one, the error return way affects how it is encoded into MessagePack response packet. When the function throws, and the error reaches the top stack frame without being caught, it is encoded as IPROTO_ERROR (82) and IPROTO_ERROR_24 (49).

When the error object is returned as a regular value, not as an exception, it is encoded also as a regular value, inside IPROTO_DATA (48). Just like a string, a number, a tuple, etc.

With encoding as IPROTO_ERROR/IPROTO_ERROR_24 there is no much of a configuration space. Format of these values can't be changed. IPROTO_ERROR is always returned as a MessagePack map, with a stack of errors in it. IPROTO_ERROR_24 is always an error message. The IPROTO_ERROR_24 field is kept for compatibility with connectors to Tarantool versions < 2.4.1.

With encoding as a part of IPROTO_DATA you can choose serialization way using `error_marshaling_enabled` option. When it is true, errors are encoded as MessagePack extension type MP_EXT, and contain the whole error stack, encoded exactly like IPROTO_ERROR value. When the option is false (default behaviour in 2.4.1), the error is encoded as a string, MP_STR, which is the error's message. If there is a stack of errors, only the newest error is encoded.

`error_marshaling_enabled` option exists for backward compatibility, in case your application on Tarantool wants to be compatible with old connectors, which don't support MP_EXT encoded errors.

In Tarantool < 2.4.1 errors were encoded into result MessagePack as a string with error message, and error stacks didn't exist at all. So when the new format and the error stacks feature were introduced, making the new format default would be a too radical change breaking the old connectors.

Consider these examples of how error marshaling affects results. I use Tarantool 2.4.1 console here, and built-in netbox connector. The code below can be copy pasted into the console.

First instance:

```lua
box.cfg{listen = 3313}
box.schema.user.grant('guest', 'super')

function throw_error()
    box.error({code = 1000, reason = "Error message"})
end

function return_error()
    return box.error.new({code = 1000, reason = "Error message"})
end
```

Second instance:

```lua
netbox = require('net.box')
c = netbox.connect(3313)
```

Now I try to call the function on the second instance:

```
tarantool> c:call('throw_error')
---
- error: Error message
...
```

The `c:call('throw_error')` threw an exception. If I catch it using `pcall()` Lua function, I will see the error object.

```
tarantool> ok, err = pcall(c.call, c, 'throw_error')
tarantool> err:unpack()
---
- code: 1000
  base_type: ClientError
  type: ClientError
  message: Error message
  trace:
  - file: '[string "function throw_error()..."]'
    line: 2
...
```

As you can see, I didn't set `error_marshaling_enabled`, but got the full error. Now I will call the other function, without exceptions. But the error object won't be full.

```
tarantool> err = c:call('return_error')
tarantool> err
---
- Error message
...
tarantool> err:unpack()
---
- error: '[string "return err:unpack()"]:1: attempt to call method ''unpack'' (a nil
    value)'
...
```

The error was returned as a mere string, error message. Not as an error object. Now I will turn on the marshaling:

```
tarantool> c:eval('box.session.settings.error_marshaling_enabled = true')
---
...
tarantool> err = c:call('return_error')
---
...
tarantool> err:unpack()
---
- code: 1000
  base_type: ClientError
  type: ClientError
  message: Error message
  trace:
  - file: '[C]'
    line: 4294967295
...
```

Now the same function returned the error in the new format, more featured.

On the summary: `error_marshaling_enabled` affects only returned errors. Not thrown errors.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!